# Mongoose not populating array in Mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, api, mongoose

Here is my Game Schema :

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

const GameSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },

    publishers: [
        {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'Publisher'
        }
    ]
});

var GameModel = mongoose.model('Game', GameSchema);
module.exports = GameModel;
```

Here is my Publisher Schema :

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

const PublisherSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    companyName: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },

    firstParty: {
        type: Boolean,
        required: true
    },

    website: {
        website: String,
    }
});

var PublisherModel = mongoose.model('Publisher', PublisherSchema);

module.exports = PublisherModel;
```

I have a picture of what you can find in my collection "games" in mongoDB :

[image]

When I use this route :

```
router.get('/games', async function(req, res) {

    const games = await Game
        .find()
        .populate('publishers')
        .select('title publishers')

        res.json(games);
})
```

I have empty arrays as result for the publishers. If I don't use an array in Schema, this is correcly populated and I got data of publisher into each game. So why mongoose doesn't populate when it is an array?

Comment: Mongoose can populate array. May be the reason is the `.select()`. Try removing it and see if the populate work or not.

Comment: I tried, the result is the same, I got an empty array. If I remove the array and change schema to have a unique value, and let this code exactly the same, populate works. So the fact that it is an array is the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check below by modifying the schema definition as below

I think the below could fix your issue, please give a try by redefining the publishers as below

```
Publishers: [
        publisher: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'Publisher'
       }
   ]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the definition of schema is more about to define the structure of the object that we would like to process, rather about the number of objects that we want to process.

The Schema definition with what I know is defining the semantics of the model and to take advantage of the middle ware functionalities.

You can  save multiple objects of which meet the same semantic definition but the definition itself cannot be an array

Thanks
Pavan

Comment: So how could I have many publishers by game? And what about $push when update?